# iOS Data Storage Guidelines. in this situation what should i do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I got rejection leter from apple stating that my app does not follow "iOS Data Storage Guidelines"
so here what i have it is a dictionary app which has 3 sqlite databases 2 bookmarks and dictionary database it self. I will be pushing updates every month which overwrites dictionary.sqlite if update is avaliable  right now all of these are in /document folder what you guys suggest I do i'm pretty confuesd. thanks for your help.

Comment: This is something you really need to ask Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The document is here: http://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

I'd be more specific, but I'm still waiting for approval at the moment, so I can't read this myself yet.

Comment: i been through all the instruction i was thinking a private document folder under library but not sure need more advice

Comment: As I said: still waiting approval, so I can't read this, and the Apple NDAs prevent sharing of this doc, so can't help much ATM.  My guess is that the rejection relates to iCloud sync settings, or disk space clearing that iOS apparently now does automatically.  (You need to mark what is and is not eligible)

Comment: oh dang it this should help http://www.chrisboyd.net/2011/11/icloud-and-the-new-ios-data-storage-guidelines/

Comment: so bookmarks which is user data it should be in /document folder and dictionary.sqlite which is app database and its private should be in private folder or cache cant put it in cache folder because it will get purged. dang im really confuesd

Comment: I've read that "document" through five times and I still can't make sense of it.